# Creating an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send an intent to Photoshop Express which now accepts raw images.  In this example I'm sending a Canon CR2 file.  Regardless of how I specify the action, data, or type I can't seem to get PSE to pop up as an option.

PSE manifest:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.adobe.psmobile.PSXEditActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.adobe.psmobile.MainActivity"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/png"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:host="*"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cr2"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.CR2"/>
                ...
```

One of hundreds of attempted combinations:

```
//        Intent action = new Intent();
        Intent action = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
//        action.setType("*/*");
        action.setData(media.getUri());
        action.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        action.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(action, getResources().getString(R.string.edit));
        startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
```

Ex uri:

```
file:///storage/sdcard1/_test/canon_1d_miv_03.CR2
```

ES File explorer will send a CR2 file to PSE, but I can't under any circumstances get it to appear as an option for anything but jpeg.  Does anyone know how to format the intent that PSE would consume?

Comment: Do you mean you can modify PSE intent filters?

Comment: "Regardless of how I specify the action, data, or type I can't seem to get PSE to pop up as an option" -- unfortunately, we cannot see your attempts from here, as you did not paste them into your question, and your monitor is turned the wrong way for us to read over your shoulder. :-) Off the cuff, it looks like `ACTION_EDIT` with a `file:///` `Uri` ending in `.cr2` should work, though `pathPattern` is a notoriously aggravating `<intent-filter>` option.

Comment: It'd be impossible to add all the options I used, since many were deleted along the mad dash.  Suffice to say I went so far as to invent types: "*/.cr2", etc.  I've used the methods to pull mime types, but those only apply to official Android mimes.  I've used multiple actions to ensure edit wasn't simply wrong.  I've tried (no joking) about 100 combinations in desperation.  I was hoping this would be a matter of getting the 'right' answer rather than finding out what is 'wrong' with my million attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not this was the answer:

```
    Intent action = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    action.setDataAndType(media.getUri(), "");
```

Note the empty string as type.  The only other thing that produced options was "*/*", but that showed dozens of apps.

I still don't understand why the empty string worked, so if anyone has an explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are opening files in ES file explorer, well maybe it has set defaults for some file extensions?

Try re-setting them by:

1. Long click on an item
2. More
3. Open As
4. Clear defaults

[image]

You may need to do this multiple times for separate extensions.

Comment: No, this is a legit stackoverflow question regarding coding the intent.  I bring ES explorer up because it somehow brings up PSE as an option, so it can be done...somehow.

Comment: @Anthony when you clear the defaults PSE **is** brought up as an option.

Comment: I'm using an intent chooser so it avoids the defaults anyway (ACTION_EDIT actually crashes if you don't use a chooser).

Comment: @Anthony not sure I understand what you're doing but perhaps you should target all images with `android:mimeType="image/*"`

Comment: image/* technically means jpeg, png, bmp, webp, or gif.  It only applies to the built-in support for images.  A cr2 is an unknown mime type, though like I said, ES File Explorer creates a proper intent somehow.